# Change default layout in GeoExplorer from MapQuest to something else

Tags: geoserver, geoexplorer, mapquest, default

By default if you open a view or a table in geoxplorer from geoserver it loads your layer on top of the mapQuest layout. But mapQuest is not available anymore.

I tried looking in every config options and file i found i cannot find how to load another layout by default. I can change it manually no problem but not by default.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my composer.html file (which I can not send you here) and replace original file with this one. See last part with osm and compare with that section in original file.

```
<!-- PrintPreview resources -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../externals/printpreview/resources/css/printpreview.css">

<script>
    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = "../theme/app/img/blank.gif";
    OpenLayers.ImgPath = "../theme/app/img/";
    // optionally set locale based on query string parameter
    if (GeoExt.Lang) {
        GeoExt.Lang.set(OpenLayers.Util.getParameters()["locale"] || GeoExt.Lang.locale);
    }
    var app = new GeoExplorer.Composer({
        authStatus: {{status}},
        proxy: "../proxy/?url=",
        printService: "/geoserver/pdf/",
        about: {
            title: "GeoExplorer Demo Map",
            "abstract": "This is a demonstration of GeoExplorer, an " +
                "application for assembling and publishing web-based maps. " +
                "After adding layers to the map, use the 'Publish map' " +
                "tool to embed this map in any web page.",
            contact: "For more information, contact <a href='http://boundlessgeo.com'>Boundless</a>."
        },
        defaultSourceType: "gxp_wmscsource",
        sources: {
            local: {
                url: "/geoserver/ows",
                title: "Local GeoServer",
                ptype: "gxp_wmscsource"
            },
            csw: {
                url: "/geoserver/csw",
                ptype: "gxp_cataloguesource",
                yx: {'urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326': true}
            },
            suite: {
                url: "http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows",
                title: "Remote Suite GeoServer"
            },
            mapquest: {
                ptype: "gxp_mapquestsource"
            },
            osm: {
                ptype: "gxp_osmsource"
            },
            google: {
                ptype: "gxp_googlesource"
            },
            bing: {
                ptype: "gxp_bingsource"
            },
            mapbox: {
                ptype: "gxp_mapboxsource"
            },
            ol: {
                ptype: "gxp_olsource"
            }
        },
        map: {
            projection: "EPSG:102113",
            layers: [{
                source: "osm",
                title: "OpenStreetMap",
                name: "mapnik",
                group: "background"
            }, {
                source: "ol",
                group: "background",
                fixed: true,
                type: "OpenLayers.Layer",
                args: [
                    "None", {visibility: false}
                ]
            }],
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        }
    });
</script>
```